# Extract flicker video thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript, video, embed

I have to make a video gallery , where users will upload flicker video link. I need thumbnails of video. how can i do it using javascript/php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you need thumbnail of this video http://www.flickr.com/photos/mariareyesmcdavis/3478595161/

Make following HTTP request using php curl .

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/?url={flicker video url}&format=json

http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/?url=http%3A//www.flickr.com/photos/mariareyesmcdavis/3478595161/&format=json
```

You will get a json response from flicker

```
{
    "type":"video",
    "title":"Wordpress Blog Design and Social Marketing Project",
    "author_name":"Maria Reyes-McDavis",
    "author_url":"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/mariareyesmcdavis\/",
    "width":500,"height":375,
    "web_page":"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/mariareyesmcdavis\/3478595161\/",
    "thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/farm4.staticflickr.com\/3570\/3478595161_7c2845616e_m.jpg",
    "thumbnail_width":"240",
    "thumbnail_height":"180",
    "web_page_short_url":"http:\/\/flic.kr\/p\/6ioH9D",
    "html":"<object type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"500\" height=\"375\" data=\"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/apps\/video\/stewart.swf?v=109786\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\"> <param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"intl_lang=en-us&photo_secret=7c2845616e&photo_id=3478595161&flickr_show_info_box=true\"><\/param> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/apps\/video\/stewart.swf?v=109786\"><\/param> <param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#000000\"><\/param> <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><\/param><embed type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/apps\/video\/stewart.swf?v=109786\" bgcolor=\"#000000\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" flashvars=\"intl_lang=en-us&photo_secret=7c2845616e&photo_id=3478595161&flickr_show_info_box=true\" height=\"375\" width=\"500\"><\/embed><\/object>",
    "license":"Attribution-ShareAlike License",
    "license_url":"http:\/\/creativecommons.org\/licenses\/by-sa\/2.0\/",
    "license_id":"5","version":"1.0",
    "cache_age":3600,
    "provider_name":"Flickr",
    "provider_url":"http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/"
}
```

Now grab "thumbnail_url" from response

Answer (score 0):

Extract **photo id** & **photo secret** from embed code of flickr (you already knows very well)
then, follow it:

```
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=7bcd4d0a48fc6fe0e86ec660f95541a9&photo_id=$flickr_photo_id&secret=$flickr_photo_secret&format=php_serial"));    
$video_url = $hash['photo']['urls']['url'][0]['_content']; 
$hash2 = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/?url=$video_url&format=php_serial"));
return $hash2['thumbnail_url'];
```